# call form1_load() from form2 in C#

Tags: c#

this is my code

form1

```
private void Master_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            load();
        }
        public void load()
        {
            //some code
        }
```

form 2

```
private void buttonTambah_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Master mstr = new Master();
    mstr.load();
    this.Close();
}
```

i want when form2 buttonTambah_Click is Clicked and close, form1 run Master_Load

//sorry for bad english

Comment: And why isn't it working? What error did you get? What access modifier does form1 have?

Comment: How you are calling the Form2 from master?

Comment: When you *show* `mstr`, it'll execute the form's `OnLoad` event.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to call it... You just do;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Master frm = new Master();
    frm.Show();
}
// Create Form2.
public class Master: Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        Text = "Master";
    }
}
```

From:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws1btzy8(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: And how it answers the question? OP having a form called master, and there is another form called form2. and he wanted to call the `load` method of master from the form2 object

Comment: @un-lucky I was informing him he doesn't need to call the load method, it is called automatically when form is shown. This is too trivial a question to merit a real answer, he should RTFM that I linked. There you go, have changed name if it pleases you

Answer (score 0):

> run Master_Load

You generally don't invoke event handler methods *directly*.  They're meant to respond to actual events.  In this case, the `OnLoad` event of the form.  In order to trigger that event, you just need to "load" the form.  Basically, show the form.  Something like this:

```
Master mstr = new Master();
mstr.Show(); // show the form
```

In the process of showing the form, the Windows Forms framework will invoke `Master_Load()` to handle that event.  Which it appears internally will call `load()` in your code.

Comment: if i use this, then there is 2 form Master.

Comment: @andruwoei: Only if you're showing a second one somewhere.  The code you've provided only has *one* instance of `Master`.  If you're creating two, but don't want two, then only create one.